# Could not resolve all artifacts for configuration ':classpath'. > Could not resolve io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.26.1

Tags: nativescript, nativescript-firebase

I am building a Nativescript app using nativescript-firebase-plugin. I have the app working on my Windows 10 machine, but wanted to run both Android and IOS at the same time, so I got a Mac and began porting over the app. I went through the docs on how to set it up. tns doctor is returning that everything is OK, but I keep getting the above error when trying to build.

Here is my package.json

```
{
  "nativescript": {
    "id": "org.nativescript.myapp",
    "tns-ios": {
      "version": "6.5.0-2020-02-10-163848-01"
    },
    "tns-android": {
      "version": "6.4.1"
    }
  },
  "description": "NativeScript Application",
  "license": "SEE LICENSE IN <your-license-filename>",
  "repository": "<fill-your-repository-here>",
  "scripts": {},
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "~8.2.0",
    "@angular/common": "~8.2.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "~8.2.0",
    "@angular/core": "~8.2.0",
    "@angular/forms": "~8.2.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~8.2.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~8.2.0",
    "@angular/router": "~8.2.0",
    "nativescript-angular": "~8.2.0",
    "nativescript-imagepicker": "^7.1.0",
    "nativescript-plugin-firebase": "^10.3.3",
    "nativescript-theme-core": "~1.0.6",
    "nativescript-ui-autocomplete": "^6.0.0",
    "nativescript-ui-sidedrawer": "^8.0.0",
    "reflect-metadata": "~0.1.12",
    "rxjs": "^6.4.0",
    "tns-core-modules": "^6.4.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.9.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~8.2.0",
    "@ngtools/webpack": "8.2.0",
    "codelyzer": "~4.5.0",
    "nativescript-dev-webpack": "^1.5.0",
    "node-sass": "^4.7.1",
    "tslint": "~5.19.0",
    "typescript": "~3.5.3"
  }
}
```

Here is my firebase.nativescript.json

```
{
    "using_ios": true,
    "using_android": true,
    "analytics": false,
    "firestore": true,
    "realtimedb": false,
    "authentication": true,
    "remote_config": false,
    "performance_monitoring": false,
    "external_push_client_only": false,
    "messaging": false,
    "in_app_messaging": false,
    "crashlytics": false,
    "storage": true,
    "functions": false,
    "facebook_auth": true,
    "google_auth": false,
    "admob": false,
    "dynamic_links": false,
    "ml_kit": false
}
```

From what I've gathered, it appears this io.fabric.tools has something to do with Google crashlytics, so I made sure to remove it from my firebase plugin and also removed google auth. None of that seemed to make a difference.

Comment: Did you try a clean build after disabling crashlytics?

Comment: I deleted hooks, node_modules, platforms and package-lock.json and then ran npm i. Is there something else?

Comment: Also I just ran an tns run android --clean. Same error.

Comment: If you have disabled crashlytics and performed a clean build, that should prevent fabric libraries. You must check with the plugin author, there are a couple related issues in Github, may be going through them might give you something.